# Color hyperlinks individually

Tags: hyperref

How can I individually set the color of the hyperlinks ? It currently has a red box around it.

```
\href{www.google.com}{Test}
```

How can I select its color ? Like

```
\href{www.google.com}{Test}{boxcolor=blue}
```

I have many other boxes to put with different colors so Id rather repeatedly type a short idiot-friendly method then redefine the function definitions.

Comment: Reading the manual of `hyperref` helps: `\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}`, for example

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - But it doesn't help that much.  `urlcolor` is the one you want, but it only works with `colorlinks=true`.  I think the box colors are chosen by the PDF viewer.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: True, I missed that it is about  urls

Comment: `\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=orange]{hyperref}`  to avoid the ugly boxes and fix a default organge color for URL links, and then  `\href{http://www.example.com}{\color{blue}www.example.com}`  to make a individual link in blue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `{\color{<color>}\url{<url>}}` or `\href{<url>}{\color{<color>}<text>}`. A macro could simplify only a little this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\newcommand\colorlink[3]{\href{#2}{\color{#1}#3}}
\newcommand\colorurl[2]{{\color{#1}\url{#2}}}
\linespread{1.3}

\begin{document}

\obeylines

\href{http://www.example.com}{www.example.com} 
\colorlink{purple}{http://www.example.com}{www.example.com}  
\colorlink{violet}{http://www.example.com}{www.example.com}{blue}   
\colorlink{blue}{http://www.example.com}{www.example.com}{cyan}  

\bigskip

\url{http://www.example.com}
\colorurl{purple}{http://www.example.com}
\colorurl{violet}{http://www.example.com}
\colorurl{blue}{http://www.example.com}

\end{document}
```

In the odd case that you want link boxes instead of colored text, remove any package option incompatible with that boxes (e.g.  `colorlinks` or `hidelinks`)  and then use some like:

```
\hypersetup{urlbordercolor=orange} 
\url{http://www.example.com}
\hypersetup{urlbordercolor=cyan}   % return to default color
```